# How to create a new list with just numbers and words/phrases from a original list with both numbers and words in python?

Tags: python, list

The current list looks like this: 
`line_list = ['Rent 350', 'Gas  60', 'Food 50', 'Clothing 40', 'Car Payment 500', 'Electric Bill 150', 'Cell Phone Bill 150', 'Miscellaneous 10']`

I would like the output to look like this:

```
labels = ['Rent', 'Gas', 'Food', 'Clothing', 'Car Payment', 'Electric Bill', 'Cell Phone Bill', 'Miscellaneous']
amount = ['350', '60', '50', '40','500','150', '150', '10']
```

Basically, I'm trying to split the list into one list with just numbers and one list with the words/phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
line_list = ['Rent 350', 'Gas  60', 'Food 50', 'Clothing 40', 'Car Payment 500', 'Electric Bill 150', 'Cell Phone Bill 150', 'Miscellaneous 10']

expenses = []
costs = []

for *expense, cost in map(str.split, line_list):
    expenses.append(" ".join(expense))
    costs.append(cost)
```

Comment: What does    *expense do? And thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Packs everything **but** the last word (in this case a number) to a list. Beautiful solution must say

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the structure of your phrases is as in the example (some words and a number in the end), you could use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)'s [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```py
>>> import re
>>> word_list = []
>>> num_list = []
>>> for phrase in line_list:
        parts = re.split(" (?=\d)", phrase)
        word_list.append(parts[0])
        num_list.append(parts[1])

>>> word_list
['Rent', 'Gas ', 'Food', 'Clothing', 'Car Payment', 'Electric Bill', 'Cell Phone Bill', 'Miscellaneous']
>>> num_list
['350', '60', '50', '40', '500', '150', '150', '10']
```

You might get tempted to use list-comprehension here but that would mean going over the list twice, so an old-fashioned loop will be best to loop once and create both lists.

Comment: Thanks! This also answered my question. Quick question, what does (?=\d) do exactly?

Comment: The `?=` means a *positive look-ahead*. That asserts that the regex matches after the current position. The `\d` is meta sequence that matches any number. It is equivalent and shorthand for `[0-9]`